# Django - Use of inspectdb for user's uploaded table

Tags: django, django-models, django-celery, inspectdb

My web application allow users to load/create tables in the Postgres database. I know Django ORM needs a model definition in models.py for each table in the database to access it.

I wonder if I could call manage.py inspectdb from a script after an upload (or a delete) to auto-generates the models.py.

If I use queues with django-celery to be sure that every inspectdb are done one at a time, could it be a viable solution?

Thank you for your comments and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can call commands with

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('inspectdb')
```

see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) for more info.

But I doubt it would work for dynamically creating models the way you want. For one thing, most wsgi servers need to be rebooted for changes to appear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am testing PostGreSQL hstore capability instead.